# How to handle 'Forbidden' exception in Teams bot app when trying to send meeting notifications?

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

Using the New Teams toolkit for Visual Studio, I created a .Net/C# bot app, starting with the sample of an Echobot which comes with the Teams toolkit for visual studio. Here is the link to my repo for reference to the error and for you to be able to repro the error- https://github.com/messibarbie/Csbot2

In this bot app, I tried adding the functionality of sending meeting notification to targeted users by taking help of this sample (https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/meetings-notification/csharp/InMeetingNotifications) provided by Microsoft where the expected result would have been as shown in the screenshot below-
[image]

However, when I click the button "Send Notification", I am getting a "forbidden" error. I have attached the detail of the exception below. I added the "OnlineMeetingNotification.Send.Chat" resource specific permission in the manifest to be able to send the notification and information like app id, password were provided using builder.Configuration. Then what is causing the issue here to generate the notification and what does this "Forbidden" status code mean? Is it some authentication issue which is causing this? What is expected from my end to fix this issue?
Below I have given the full description of the exception.

> Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
> at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Teams.TeamsOperations.SendMeetingNotificationMessageAsync(String meetingId, MeetingNotificationBase notification, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Teams.TeamsOperationsExtensions.SendMeetingNotificationAsync(ITeamsOperations operations, String meetingId, MeetingNotificationBase notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Teams.TeamsInfo.SendMeetingNotificationAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, MeetingNotificationBase notification, String meetingId, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Csbot2.Bot.EchoBot.HandleActions(ITurnContext`1 turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\x\y\Csbot2\Csbot2\Bot\EchoBot.cs:line 99

Screenshots of my app when trying to send the targeted notification:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can not reproduce your error using your repo. Would you please share the steps how you run this app?

Comment: @BowenSong once you open the solution in VS, you need to 1st select a devtunnel. Then prepare Teams App dependencies by right clicking on project -> Select Teams toolkit -> Click prepare Teams App Dependencies.
After that, you will be prompted to select the desired Microsoft account which you want to use to create the Teams app. Select and click continue.
Once the Teams App dependencies have been prepared, click on “Microsoft Teams (browser)” to run the app. 
This'll open up a tab in your browser to allow you to sideload the Teams app. See next comment for next steps.

Comment: @BowenSong an extension to previous comment as I ran out of characters-
You will find screenshots of the below steps in the main question description.
Mention the bot app using “@” followed by the name of the bot. This should be followed by the command “SendTargetedNotification”. Send it in the chat. 
This will give you a response from the bot in the chat with the list of attendees in the meeting.
Select the user and click “Send Notification” button.

Comment: @BowenSong
The expected result would be a dialog like as shown in the Readme file from the sample bot app provided by microsoft (link to the MS sample- https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/meetings-notification/csharp ) 
Instead of the dialog, I am getting the forbidden error.

Comment: I followed your steps and this app still works for me. Would you please try to add a breakpoint on SendMeetingNotificationAsync line and see whether selectedMembers and meetingId is valid?